# How to migrate JSF Validator to Bean Validation?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

The usual way to perform JSF validation in an imperative manner is to add validator tag to JSF and have a corresponding `Validator` class like the following :

View:

```
<h:outputLabel for="email" value="*Enter Email: " title="Primary Email"/>
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{personView.per.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="email is required"  
title="Primary Email" tabindex="3"> 
  <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="m2a" for="email" style="color:red"/> <p></p>
```

`Validator`:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    log("Validating submitted email -- " + value.toString());
    matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());

    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      FacesMessage msg =
              new FacesMessage(" E-mail validation failed.",
              "Please provide E-mail address in this format: abcd@abc.com");
      msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

      throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
  }
```

Now here the validation is getting triggered by the JSF. I want to change that part and want that the validation is instead triggered from another Controller via a Bean Validation constraint. That means that, I want to remove the following part :-

```
<f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
```

and want that this validation is triggered from another controller via a Bean Validation constraint.
Note that, I cannot add the constraint directly on the entity as the entity is a generated file. I want do the validation in the controller itself such that incase of error I could show the error message on the UI.
How can I go about it?

Explanation with some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use bean validation on the entity, it will only validate when you try to persist/update? There are also PrePersist and PreUpdate events on the entity, where you can make conditional validation. You can trigger these validations manually, if you don't want to save the entities to a database

Comment: Well, the application I am working on is a bit strange. Entity files are generated based on some configuration. So that is not an option. :(

Comment: I can't see the question, what do you mean by how? you can just look for some tutoriels and start, what are the difficulties you have encountered?